# Sequence counter in a hardwired control unit

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

I have been studying the structure of a hardwired control unit and at 8:57 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLgXUPOjKEc)

we get a basic block diagram.What does the sequence counter do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

For a basic cpu each instruction takes multiple clock cycles to execute. For example you could have steps that

1. first read the instruction into the instruction register,
2. then it reads operand 1 into the execution unit input register, and
3. then it reads operand 2 into the execution unit input register, and
4. then it reads from the output register into the destination register.

therefore you need a counter to keep track of which step of instruction execution you are in.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense!